# How to create a multi level folder structure for unit testing

Tags: java, junit

I need a folder structure like this:

```
home
    --level1
        --level2a
        --level2b
```

I can create the first level with junit's temporary directory, but how do you create the levels below it?

```
 @Rule
    public TemporaryFolder home= new TemporaryFolder();

    @Before
    public void setUp() 
    {
        File level1= home.newFolder("level1");
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
package com.sandbox;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.rules.TemporaryFolder;

import java.io.File;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

public class SandboxTest {

    @Rule
    public TemporaryFolder folder = new TemporaryFolder();
    private File level1;
    private File level2a;
    private File level2b;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        level1 = folder.newFolder("level1");
        level2a = folder.newFolder("level1/level2a");
        level2b = folder.newFolder("level1/level2b");
    }

    @Test
    public void whenCreatingNestedFoldersThenAllGetDeleted() {
        assertTrue(level1.exists());
        assertTrue(level2a.exists());
        assertTrue(level2b.exists());

        System.out.println(level1.getAbsolutePath());
    }

}
```

It will work exactly as you'd expect.  All will be cleaned up after the test runs.

Comment: This answer is no longer valid for junit 4.12. Folder name cannot consist of multiple path components separated by a file separator. Please use newFolder('MyParentFolder','MyFolder') to create hierarchies of folders.

Comment: As @MrKiller21 says, the right way to run the example is:

Answer (score 3):

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.rules.TemporaryFolder;

import java.io.File;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

public class SandboxTest {

    @Rule
    public TemporaryFolder folder = new TemporaryFolder();
    private File level1;
    private File level2a;
    private File level2b;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        level1 = folder.newFolder("level1");
        level2a = folder.newFolder("level1", "level2a");
        level2b = folder.newFolder("level1", "level2b");
    }

    @Test
    public void whenCreatingNestedFoldersThenAllGetDeleted() {
        assertTrue(level1.exists());
        assertTrue(level2a.exists());
        assertTrue(level2b.exists());

        System.out.println(level1.getAbsolutePath());
    }

}
```